# Заблокировали приложение в PlayMarket

Tags: android

Написал видеоплеер для проигрывания местного телеканала, в исходном коде в переменной в качестве источника для проигрывателя была указана ссылка на телеканал. Загрузил приложение в маркет, но в процессе модерации оно было отклонено и причина была указана что я не обладаю правами на домен, который был указан в качестве источника для плеера. Собственно так оно и есть у меня нет прав на его использование, но в маркете куча ТВ приложений. Вопрос у меня такой как в таком случае указать ссылку на телеканал, чтобы приложение не блокировали? Я не думаю что все разработчики таких приложений купили права на использование доменов, которые являются источниками для плеера. Как обычно поступают в таком случае?

Comment: В названии приложения как-то фигурировало название телеканала?

Comment: Нет, не фигурировало

Comment: а что было написано в описании приложения? Просто маловерятно, что они придрались к переменной в исходном коде

Comment: Дагестан ТВ было в названии приложения

Comment: Сделайте попроще название, а телеканал добавьте к описанию. По идее так индексироваться тоже будет. Просто саппорту гугла проще не пропустить приложение, нежели разбираться кто прав.

Comment: Я боюсь уже это приложение выкладывать)) это было на моем первом аккаунте три раза отклонили и заблокировали мой аккаунт, после этого новый аккаунт создал.

Comment: Просто хотел узнать может кто-то тут сталкивался с таким

Comment: Если банили из-за этого приложения, то в первую очередь надо сменить package name и скриншоты приложения. Сам сталкивался и получал пожизненный бан. Что для себя понял - никаких "брендовых" заимствований в названии приложения да и в описании тоже желательно. Так же как и использование чужой символики, как в иконке так и в скриншотах. Но бывает, что саппорт сам пишет что именно следует сменить в оформлении, чтобы приложение прошло

Comment: Понял, спасибо за информацию лучше не буду рисковать. Мне они писали, если я смогу подтвердить права на домен, то приложение одобрят, но я конечно же этого не могу сделать. Телеканал спутниковый, республиканский может поэтому.